# saving and displaying embedded video in WooCommerce / WC Vendor Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom text field to woocommerce and also displayed it in the frontend of `WC Vendor pro`. So vendors can add a youtube or vimeo link to embed their movies.

However for some reason I can't get it to save and display in the product page on the front end.

The code I have so far in **`functions.php`**:

```
// Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

  // Text Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
  array( 
    'id'          => 'video_url', 
    'label'       => __( 'Your product video link (youtube/vimeo)', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => 'https://',
    'desc_tip'    => 'true',
    'description' => __( 'Copy the Youtube or Vimeo link here', 'woocommerce' ) 
  )
);

  echo '</div>';

}

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

  // Text Field
  $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['video_url'];
  if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'video_url', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

}
```

And to display the field in the **vendor section**:

```
<div class="all-100">
        <!-- Media uploader -->
        <div class="wcv-product-media">
            <?php BuddyBoss_BM_Templates::product_media_uploader( $object_id ); ?>  
            <?php woo_add_custom_general_fields( $object_id ); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

So now vendors can enter the field. However saving nor displaying it won't work. I added the following to the **product page**:

```
echo $youtubevideo_code = wp_oembed_get( get_field('video_url') );
// tried this one as well:
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_url', true );
```

Thanks any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use acf to use `get_field`, i think you miss the second parameter $post_id, the function need to know the post id of the field you want to get.

```
echo $youtubevideo_code = wp_oembed_get( get_field('video_url') );
```

You must right it like this

```
global $post; // I don't know where is your script (in the loop ? in a function ?) 

$youtubevideo_code = wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', true )); // can be get_field('video_url, $post->ID);

echo $youtubevideo_code;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried indeed to add it, but no result. I think the link isn't saved properly either, after saving it doesn't show again. Any other ideas?